# Listing Common elements in Java

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to printout the common elements between two lists and when I try to use retainAll(); it basically skips over everything past that.

```
    List<String> dblist = Arrays.asList(db);
    List<String> medlist = Arrays.asList(medication);

    //Get Meds in Database that Match Patient Meds 
    jTextArea3.append("\nMedications in dblist :"+"\n");
    for (int d =0; d<dblist.size(); d++){
        jTextArea3.append(dblist.get(d)+"\n");
    }       

    jTextArea3.append("\nMedications in medlist :"+"\n");
    for (int d =0; d<medlist.size(); d++){
        jTextArea3.append(medlist.get(d)+"\n");
    }    

    //dblist.retainAll(medlist);
    jTextArea3.append("\nMedications in both :"+"\n");
    for (int d =0; d<dblist.size(); d++){
        jTextArea3.append(dblist.get(d)+"\n");
    }
```

This will list out the contents of dblist.get(d) but as soon as I uncomment dblist.retainAll(medlist) the output stops at the end of the medlist output above.

Comment: Probably because there are no common elements?

Comment: Is an exception thrown?  retainAll is optional  for an implementation - see the doc.  (Note, I'm taking you at your word - *nothing* further is output, not even the "Medications in both" heading)

Comment: We'd really need to see the actual data used.  As dehasi suggests it's likely that your data is different than you're expecting.

Comment: Do the two lists contain the same data type? Are they comparable (ie `equal`)?  using `retainAll` on incompatible `List`s will result in an empty result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have got UnsupportedOperationException.
Because of `retainAll` resize collection, while `Arrays.asList()` returns not resizable one.

Replace `dblist` initialization with `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(db))`

But i dont recommend to use List as argument in `retainAll` method, it will be O(N^2) complexity. Use `HashSet` for `medlist` if order of elements does not matter.

Comment: *`Arrays.asList()` returns immutable one...* Not quite. It's mutable but not resizable.

Comment: Or `LinkedHashSet` if order does matter.

Comment: Andrey... thank you! This worked (at least handling the exception I didnt realize I was getting (it was late in the day)). At least now the heading "Medications in both" is outputting. List is still blank so have to figure that out ( I know for sure at least one match between the two).